# Detect mentions of unnamed people (e.g., “policeman” or “sister”) in text

Tags: nlp

I am looking for a program or library that can detect mentions of unnamed people (e.g.,  “policeman” or “sister”). Typical named-entity packages such as  [spaCy](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy-ent?text=The%20sister%20left%20the%20policeman.&model=en_core_web_sm&ents=person%2Corg%2Cgpe%2Cloc%2Cproduct%2Cnorp%2Cdate%2Cper%2Cmisc) only recognize proper nouns (e.g., "Bob").

Example of input text:

> The sister left the policeman.

From this input text it should detect 2 unnamed people, “policeman” and “sister”.

Any license, operating system, code/natural language and price is fine.